# How to understand SQL : select *,'' as xxx?

Tags: sql, hive

How to understand SQL : select *,'' as xxx?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYj7e.png)

Comment: Your question is really unclear.

Answer (score 2):

This will select all the columns from table 'xxx' and add an extra column with empty value and name that column 'is_spam' as specified in your image.

Eg.

```
SELECT * ,'' as is_spam
FROM XXX;
```

will give this result

```
 col1 | col2 |is_spam |
+------------+----------+
| val1 | val2|        |
```

col1, col2 are already existing columns
val1, val2 are their respective values

is_spam is added with value ' ' i.e. empty string

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT *" is selecting every column from the specified table.

"'' as xxx" is an empty string where you have given the column the name "xxx". You can also read about renaming columns or giving aliases here [W3Schools - SQL Aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_as.asp).